# Getting Incognito & Proxy details in Chrome API

Tags: chrome-extension-manifest-v3

##### Is there an API to get incognito and/or proxy details in Chrome?

Firefox's [webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest) provides [incognito](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest#incognito) & [proxyInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onBeforeRequest#proxyinfo).

```json
{
  "requestId": "25484",
  "url": "https://example.com/favicon.ico",
  "originUrl": "https://example.com/",
  "method": "GET",
  "type": "main_frame",
  "timeStamp": 1573050075868,
  "frameId": 0,
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "thirdParty": false,
  "proxyInfo": {
    "connectionIsolationKey": "",
    "failoverTimeout": 5,
    "host": "1.1.1.1",
    "port": 4443,
    "proxyAuthorizationHeader": "",
    "proxyDNS": false,
    "type": "https",
    "username": ""
  },
  "ip": null,
  "frameAncestors": [],
  "urlClassification": {
    "firstParty": [],
    "thirdParty": []
  },
  "requestSize": 0,
  "responseSize": 0,
  "tabId": 237,
  "incognito": false
}
```

Chrome's [webRequest.onBeforeRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/api/webRequest#event-onBeforeRequest) does not provide incognito and/or proxy details.

```json
{
  "documentId": "DCB...0EE",
  "documentLifecycle": "active",
  "frameId": 0,
  "frameType": "outermost_frame",
  "initiator": "https://example.com",
  "method": "GET",
  "parentFrameId": -1,
  "requestId": "1418",
  "tabId": 1999507272,
  "timeStamp": 1702847041866.347,
  "type": "image",
  "url": "https://example.com/favicon.ico"
}
```

Comment: There's no such API. The proxy info is unobtainable, AFAIK, whereas `incognito` can be obtained in two ways: asynchronously via chrome.tabs.get or synchronously by maintaining a map of incognito tab ids using chrome.tabs.onCreated and forcing the background script to [stay alive](/a/66618269).

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you. It was a shot in the dark. Unfortunately, those options are not suitable for this purpose.